# POST an array using AJAX to PHP (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm a complete beginner with webdev, I'm trying to post the selectedCategories array to the PHP file named 'searchMatthew.php' but I can't seem to have it working. The JS file is also ran inside searchMatthew.php file. I would appreciate any kinds of help! Thanks.

**PHP:**

```
 <?php 
    $searchWord = "";
    if(isset($_POST['selectedCategories'])){
        echo "SUCCESSFUL";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['companies'])){

    }
    if(isset($_POST['word'])){
        $searchWord = $_POST['word'];
        echo $searchWord;
    }


    ?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var selectedCompanies = new Array;
var selectedCategories = new Array;

$("input:checkbox.categories").change(function () {
    selectedCategories = new Array;
    $('input.categories:checked').each(function () {
        selectedCategories.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'selectedCategories': selectedCategories
        },
        url: "searchMatthew.php",
        success: function () {
            alert(selectedCategories);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `success` callback function expects to take a response parameter. The `data` property describes the data that you are sending *over* to PHP, so that you have a string (key) to reference your data inside of $_POST.

When PHP returns a response, `selectedCategories` still refers to the data you *sent* to PHP, not the data *returned* by PHP.

From [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> success Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR
>   jqXHR ) A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function
>   gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server,
>   formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the
>   status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

You should write your code like this instead:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {'selectedCategories':selectedCategories},
      url: "searchMatthew.php",
      success: function(data){
         alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: After seeing the content of alert(data), I saw that Successful was printed inside the data variable but not in the php page itself.
What do I do such that the "Successful" will be printed inside the opened "searchMatthew.php"?

Comment: Are you sure that you understand the purpose of AJAX? AJAX allows the browser to send a request to a PHP page and retrieve a response *without* the user having to leave their current page. You shouldn't actually *see* the PHP page when you execute an AJAX request. You simply use the PHP script to return data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ajax post shortcut `$.post(url[,data][,callback])`

You're also missing the return variable from your success callback. So change your success callback like so:

```
$.post('searchMatthew.php', {'selectedCategories': selectedCategories}, function(xData, status){
     alert(xData); //should be "SUCCESSFUL"
});
```